# Is there a regular expression that validates data serialized by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, serialization

I have a large database with a bunch of serialized data that is invalid.

The data was serialized by PHP and in every case were unserializing fails the string length is off for one of the values.

```
a:2:{s:7:"example";s:14:"This one works";s:11:"example_two";s:50:"This one is broken";}
```

I would like to export all of the serialized data to a CSV, find all of the broken fields and either repair or delete them.

I would think this could be done with a regular expression... For each line find every s:[length], check that the quoted value after the next colon is equal in length to the number [length].  If the lengths don't match return the entire line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Super bonus if you can provide a mysql query that returns rows with broken serialized data.

Comment: Just curious how this would happen unless the database fields were updated to remove characters?

Comment: I have no idea how it happened... In almost every case the data is related to users who have not used the system in at least 2 years. I don't know anything beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

This could probably be cleaned up a bit, but works:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/s:\d+:"([^"]+)"/',
                                function($m) {
                                    return 's:'.strlen($m[1]).':"'.$m[1].'"';
                                }, $string);
```

- Match the string component
- Replace the length component with the `strlen()` of the matched string

On the MySQL side you can try [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp).

Comment: This is cool but I am looking for something that does not use php.  I want to hand it off to my Unix admins who use a bunch of Unix tools that can use regular expressions.  They do not like to use PHP for whatever reason.

Comment: Good luck! There's an off chance that it's doable.